# Program runs in sublime text editor but not in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, sublimetext, geckodriver

I have a problem. I wrote a program that harvests emails from a website using selenium in python. I wrote it inside the sublime text editor. Here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

class colors:
    RESET = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    BLACK = '\033[30m'
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
    CYAN = '\033[36m'
    WHITE = '\033[37m'
    BOLDBLACK = '\033[1;30m'
    BOLDRED = '\033[1;31m'
    BOLDGREEN = '\033[1;32m'
    BOLDYELLOW = '\033[1;33m'
    BOLDBLUE = '\033[1;34m'
    BOLDMAGENTA = '\033[1;35m'
    BOLDCYAN = '\033[1;36m'
    BOLDWHITE = '\033[1;37m'

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.emails = []
        self.opts = FirefoxOptions()
        self.opts.add_argument("--headless")
        self.opts.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.opts)
        self.read_urls()
        self.driver.close()
    def read_urls(self):
        urls = [ "https://wertweoritwoertiwoerit.com/", "https://rwteirtwertwertwertwe.com/" ]
        for url in urls:
            self.scan(url)
        #print(self.emails)
    def scan(self,url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        source_code = self.driver.page_source
        body = self.driver.find_element("css selector", "body")
        visible_text = body.text
        edited_visible_text = visible_text.replace("\n", " ")
        array = edited_visible_text.split(' ')
        for string in array:
            if "@" in string:
                self.emails.append(string)
                print(""+colors.BOLDBLUE + f"[+]{string}"+colors.RESET)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = App()
```

I just started that, i know the code looks awful and is poorly written, but that doesn't matter right now!

Important is: When i run Ctrl + B, OR (same functionality) press Ctrl + P and select "Build with python", then it executes and runs successfully...

**The error shows up after running the following line:**

**driver = webdriver.Firefox()**

When i then run it inside any terminal, i get this error:

```
╭─root at kali in ~kali 24-03-24 - 18:58:52
╰─○ python3 harvest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/harvest.py", line 54, in <module>
    main = App()
           ^^^^^
  File "/home/kali/harvest.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.opts)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

The sublime-text build option uses this file (without this file it doesn't work):
/root/.config/sublime-text/Lib/python33/package_control.py

Which contains:

```
import os
import sys
import zipfile

import sublime_plugin

__data_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

__pkg_path = os.path.join(__data_path, 'Packages', 'Package Control', 'package_control')
__zip_path = os.path.join(__data_path, 'Installed Packages', 'Package Control.sublime-package')

__code = None

# We check the .sublime-package first, since the sublime_plugin.ZipLoader deals with overrides
if os.path.exists(__zip_path):
    __pkg_path = os.path.join(__zip_path, 'package_control')
    __file_path = os.path.join(__pkg_path, '__init__.py')

    __loader__ = sublime_plugin.ZipLoader(__zip_path)

    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(__zip_path, 'r') as __f:
            __code = compile(
                __f.read('package_control/__init__.py').decode('utf-8'),
                '__init__.py',
                'exec'
            )
    except (OSError, KeyError):
        pass

    # may be required before Package Control has been loaded
    events = sys.modules.get('package_control.events')
    if events is None:
        events = __loader__.load_module("Package Control.package_control.events")
        events.__name__ = 'package_control.events'
        events.__package__ = 'package_control'
        sys.modules['package_control.events'] = events

elif os.path.exists(__pkg_path):
    from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

    __file_path = os.path.join(__pkg_path, '__init__.py')

    __loader__ = SourceFileLoader('package_control', __file_path)

    try:
        with open(__file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as __f:
            __code = compile(__f.read(), '__init__.py', 'exec')
    except (OSError):
        pass

    # may be required before Package Control has been loaded
    events = sys.modules.get('package_control.events')
    if events is None:
        events = SourceFileLoader('events', os.path.join(__pkg_path, 'events.py')).load_module()
        events.__name__ = 'package_control.events'
        events.__package__ = 'package_control'
        sys.modules['package_control.events'] = events

    del globals()['SourceFileLoader']

if __code is None:
    raise ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'package_control'")

__file__ = __file_path
__package__ = 'package_control'
__path__ = [__pkg_path]

# initial cleanup
del globals()['__f']
del globals()['__file_path']
del globals()['__zip_path']
del globals()['__pkg_path']
del globals()['__data_path']
del globals()['sublime_plugin']
del globals()['zipfile']
del globals()['sys']
del globals()['os']

__data = {}
exec(__code, __data)
globals().update(__data)

# Python 3.3 doesn't have __spec__
if hasattr(globals(), '__spec__'):
    __spec__.loader = __loader__
    __spec__.origin = __file__
    __spec__.submodule_search_locations = __path__
    __spec__.cached = None

# final cleanup
del globals()['__data']
del globals()['__code']
# out-dated internals
del globals()['__cached__']
```

Summary:

The code runs in subl but not in the normal terminal.

I've done a lot of research. I read that geckodriver outpust a log file, but it didn't. I don't know how to actually debug this, because i already set the paths for the firefox binary and the geckodriver driver. I added options as you can see and it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have a clue whats going on here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you verify that Sublime is running the same version of Python as you are manually using in the terminal?

Comment: An update:
Yes the version was different. So i installed pyenv and installed the same version. Now, both get the error message. I switched to multiple versions now and it doesn't work... Not even with sublime text anymore

Comment: You probably wanted to take that the other way and change the version that you use in the terminal to the one that worked in Sublime, instead of changing Sublime to the one that worked in the terminal. If you still know which version was the version that worked, you can alter the config appropriately.